# What is the different for torchvision.models.resnet and torch.hub.load?

Tags: pytorch, torchvision

There are two method for using resnet of pytorch.

methods 1:

```
import torch
model = torch.hub.load('pytorch/vision:v0.10.0', 'resnet50', pretrained=True)
model.eval()
```

methods 2:

```
import torch    
net = models.resnet50(pretrained=True)
```

Are they load the same model. If not what is the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference that there is between your models if you load them in that way it's the number of layers, since you're loading `resnet18` with *Torch Hub* and `resnet50` with *Models* (thus, also the pretrained weights). They behave differently, you can see more about that in [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/337781610_Deep_Model_Compression_via_Deep_Reinforcement_Learning).

*Torch Hub* also lets you publish pretrained models in your repository, but since you're loading it from `'pytorch/vision:v0.10.0'` (which is the same repository from which *Models* is loading the neural networks), there should be no difference between:

```
model = torch.hub.load('pytorch/vision', 'resnet18', pretrained=True)
```

and

```
model = models.resnet18(pretrained=True)
```